# Arithmetic operation while joining two tables in a sqoop query

Tags: teradata, sqoop

I have a Teradata query that runs correctly in the Teradata SQL Assistant, but shows an error when written in a `sqoop` script.

The query does a join on three tables using a condition like this:

```
...

From tableA as A \
Inner Join tableB as B\
Inner Join tableC as C \
On (B.ID = C.ID and (100*year(A.dt) + month(A.dt)) = C.curr_dt) \

...
```

The error that I get in sqoop comes from the multiplication.

```
15/01/06 00:44:01 ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.JDBCException: [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC xx.yy.zz.ww] [Error 3706] [SQLState 42000] Syntax error: expected something between '*' and the 'year' keyword.
```

Is it not possible to do arithmetic operations during a join in `sqoop`? I haven't found any resources to help me out with this. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: YEAR and MONTH are not valid Teradata SQL, both are ODBC syntax, which is automatically rewritten by the ODBC driver. Try `EXTRACT(YEAR FROM A.dt)` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YEAR and MONTH are not valid Teradata SQL, both are ODBC syntax, which is automatically rewritten by the ODBC driver.

Try `EXTRACT(YEAR FROM A.dt)` instead.